# Lenovo Y-700 incorrect fan speed

Tags: xubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad, fancontrol

My OS is Xubuntu 16.04
I have follow problem with my fan control on lenovo y-700.
After loading thinkpad_acpi module, adding options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
 and redetection sensors by lm-sensors system start to see CPU fan (or some other fan, who knows).

The problem is RMP is always 8, putting different levels does not affect speed of fan ( I heart same noise), but fan speed is not constant or full speed all the time. It is changing depend on cpu temp, unfortunately it starts to fun almost at full spedd after 35 degrees, what is too low limit.

```
status:         enabled
speed:          8
level:          auto
```

or

```
status:         disabled
speed:          8
level:          0
```

speed is always 8 and fan speed is independent of this value

Comment: and as result thinkfan programs looks like working, changing levels depend on temperature but in real world fan speed is not changing

Comment: Are there any settings in the BIOS related to fan control?

Comment: unfortunately bios settings are limited. Looks like I can setup nothing in laptop.